# Application demo for customers

Tags: xcode

I have developed a prototype of an app that I am building for some customers of mine. They would like to review the app themselves and put a portion of it on a commercial to promote it, but we are in different states.
If I build the app in Xcode and then send them the `.app` file and they load it into the directory for their other apps in iTunes and sync it onto their iPhone, will it work as expected, or do I need to get them a provisioning profile of some type?
Just looking for the most efficient way to do this without causing them any hassle.

Don't want to break any rules set out by Apple either in doing this.

Thanks!!

Comment: Apple doesn't let you distribute apps until they sign them, IIRC.

Comment: I believe you can distribute an app to a corporation instead of publicly. I.E. it isn't visible to the public, you may have to distribute it from a computer via iTunes instead of through an App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Do a video demo (web conference). You'd want to be in control during such demos. You don't want to run into issues like them being unable to install your apps on their phones during a demo.

Comment: Hi all - thanks for the replies. The customer has decided to send me an iPhone which I can then set up a provisioning profile for as part of my team and they can film the commercial as needed. I have already done a video demo for them, but understandably they would like to control how the commercial is filmed. Thanks again.